# Android: Values are not assigned when using data binding in my custom adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I'm trying to pass my binding variable for the adapter to the ViewHolder to assing values to the textviews in my adapter but the values are not assigned and the click listeners dont do anything.

Here's my adapter class:

```
class DoneAppointmentsAdapter(var context: DoneAppointmentsFragment, listener: ContentListener, var arrayList: List<Appointment>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DoneAppointmentsAdapter.ItemHolder>() {

    private val listener: ContentListener = listener
    private var binding: DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding? = null

    var activity = context
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ItemHolder {
        val viewHolder = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.done_appointments_adapter, parent, false)
        binding = DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return ItemHolder(viewHolder,binding, parent.context)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(arrayList, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    class ItemHolder(view: View, var binding: DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding?, val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        fun bind(listOfData: List<Appointment>, listener: ContentListener) {
            val dataListItem = listOfData[adapterPosition]

            binding?.donePatientItemName?.text = "${dataListItem.patientName}"
            binding?.donePatientItemTime?.text = "Some date"

            binding?.donePatientItemPatientInfo?.setOnClickListener {
                tempAppointmentId = dataListItem.id
                listener.onPatientHistoryViewClicked(dataListItem.requestedBy)
            }

            binding?.donePatientItemReviewCase?.setOnClickListener {
                amendPrescriptionWarning(dataListItem,context)
            }

            binding.donePatientItemViewCase.setOnClickListener {
                startPreview(dataListItem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure Im using the right pattern to work with databinding and adapters. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up inside `onCreateViewHolder` . you have created view twice once with the `LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)` and once with `DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding.inflate` . There should be only one in this case only`DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding` .

```
class DoneAppointmentsAdapter(var context: DoneAppointmentsFragment, listener: ContentListener, var arrayList: List<Appointment>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<DoneAppointmentsAdapter.ItemHolder>() {
    private val listener: ContentListener = listener

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): ItemHolder {
        val binding = DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context))
        return ItemHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(arrayList, listener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return arrayList.size
    }

    class ItemHolder (var binding: DoneAppointmentsAdapterBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(listOfData: List<Appointment>, listener: ContentListener) {
            val dataListItem = listOfData[adapterPosition]
            binding.donePatientItemName.text = "${dataListItem.patientName}"
            binding.donePatientItemTime.text = "Some date"
            binding.donePatientItemPatientInfo.setOnClickListener {
                tempAppointmentId = dataListItem.id
                listener.onPatientHistoryViewClicked(dataListItem.requestedBy)
            }
            binding.donePatientItemReviewCase.setOnClickListener {
                amendPrescriptionWarning(dataListItem,binding.donePatientItemReviewCase.context)
            }
            binding.donePatientItemViewCase.setOnClickListener {
                startPreview(dataListItem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should be like this . I have also removed extra useless arguments from `ItemHolder` .
To make it clear the problem with your code was `RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)` you were passing `view` while you were doing all action and stuff on `binding` those holds are two different instances of `View` . Which should be fixed with above code.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my noob mistake. Marking as solved!